# Convert HTML table to PDF(itextsharp)

Tags: c#, html, pdf, text, itext

I have got trouble parsing HTML table to PDF. Table is spreading and it's go out of page. How can I it fix?

I'm using `HTMLWorker`. It's converting HTML to PDF is good, but that table...

Here is my code(it's in method):

```
        StyleSheet ST = new StyleSheet();

        ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Arial Unicode MS");
        ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

        HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(doc);
        worker.SetStyleSheet(ST);
        worker.StartDocument();
        worker.Parse((TextReader)File.OpenText(xmlNode.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["path"].Value.ToString()));
        worker.EndDocument();
        worker.Close();
```

How can I tell `HTMLWorker` so it's create table in PDF is ok? Can I give to worker size of table?

Or maybe should I use other "workers" for example `XMLWorkerHelper` or `XMLWorker`. When I use `XMLWorker` or `XMLWorkerHelper` I can't set to "workers" my font(I need Cyrillic, and just don't understand how add font). And when I use this "workers" I have the same problem with table.
code with `XMLWorker`:

```
        //working with XMLWorker
        ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
        cssResolver.AddCss(fileCSS,true);

        CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.Parse(new FileStream(fileHTML, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
```

code with `XMLWorkerHelper`:

```
        string arialuniTff = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF");
        FontFactory.Register(arialuniTff);  

        using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileCSS)))
            {
                using (FileStream fsHtml = new FileStream(fileHTML,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, fsHtml, msCss, FontFactory.FontImp as IFontProvider);
                }
            }
```

What can You advise to me?
Thank you!

**Update**
I found one [article](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-make-cyrillic-characters-display-properly-when-converting-html-pdf) about `XMLWorkerHelper` with Cyrillic, but my code doesn't work. I can't understand why.

My code:

```
            using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileCSS)))
        {
            using (FileStream fsHtml = new FileStream(fileHTMLTest,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
            {
                XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
                fontProvider.Register(arial);
                FontFactory.FontImp = fontProvider;

                doc.Add(new Paragraph("XMLWorkerHelper"));
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("XMLWorkerHelper вот это да!"));
                iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, fsHtml, msCss, Encoding.UTF8, fontProvider);
            }
        }
```

My HTML code(test):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"content="text/html;charset=utf-8"></meta>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Привет Мир!</p>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><h2 align="center">Акционерное общество «OOO "Ландыш"»</h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p align="center">Тема:</p>
                    <p align="center">[THEME]</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>        
                    <div align="right">
                        <p>Выполнил:</p>
                        <p>[AUTHOR]</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p align="center">[CITY] [YEAR]г.</p></td>
            </tr>       
        </table>

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1, Column 1; Столбец 1, Строка 1 </td>
                <td>Row 1, Column 2; Столбец 1, Строка 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2, Column 1; Столбец 2, Строка 1</td>
                <td>Row 2, Column 2; Столбец 2, Строка 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <img src="img.jpg" alt="picture"></img>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-tables. And yes, you should be using `XMLWorker` instead of `HTMLWorker`.

Comment: I read this aritical(http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-tables) and this too(http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-convert-html-table-pdf). Why should I use `XMLWorker`? Why not `XMLWorkerHelper`? And I tried to use `XMLWorkerHelper` and `XMLWorker`. The same trouble.